# Как разбить массив на два списка по разделителю

Tags: java

Есть массив:

> [АР Крым=1, Винницкая область=2]

Как его разбить на два списка?

`List<String>region`:

> [АР Крым, Винницкая область]

`List<String>index`:

> [1, 2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно пройтись по всем элементам массива, разбить каждый на части по символу `=`, после чего сохранить полученные части в соответствующие списки:

```
String[] array = { "АР Крым=1", "Винницкая область=2" };
List<String> regions = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> indices = new ArrayList<>();
for (String str : array)
{
    String[] data = str.split("=");
    if (data.length < 2)
        continue;
    regions.add(data[0]);
    indices.add(data[1]);
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо.